# How come I get .!toplevel4.!entry when I use entry widget on a list?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```py
lbl = Label(top, text="Please enter the new company name").grid(row=1, column=1)
account_company[index] = Entry(top)
account_company[index].grid(row=3, column=1)
btn = Button(top, text="submit", command=Return).grid(row=4, column=1)
```

Whenever I run this program it allows me to enter in my info just fine but whenever I look at the list, instead of whatever I entered being shown, it says `.!toplevel4.!entry`. Why is this and how can I fix this?

Comment: What you're putting in your list is *the Entry widget itself*, which is an entirely different thing than *the text typed into the Entry*.  You would retrieve that by calling `.get()` on the Entry.

Comment: Your example code isn't sufficient for us to reproduce your problem. However, it's clear you're displaying a widget rather than the data managed by the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Well... one way of "fixing" this (the issue to fix is how the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods in the `tkinter.Entry` are defined, they are supposed to show the path to the widget so when you `print(lst_that_contains_entries)` it will call the `__repr__` method of the instance and use the returned value to display what is printed out, however for example if you were to do sth like this: `some_label.config(text=some_entry_widget)` then it would configure the text of the label by using the return value of Entry's `__str__` method) is creating a custom `Entry` class:

```py
from tkinter import Entry as tk_Entry

class Entry(tk_Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get()

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.get())
```

Then you could use it as a regular entry with the only difference being that if you print out the instance it will print out what is in the entry, and if you print out a list that contains instances of this class, you will get a list of what the entries contain.

Example below (run it and see what happens when you enter something in any of the entries and press return (enter) key):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Entry as tk_Entry


class Entry(tk_Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get()

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.get())


root = Tk()

lst = []

for _ in range(3):
    entry = Entry(root)
    entry.pack()
    entry.bind('<Return>', lambda _: print(lst))
    lst.append(entry)

root.mainloop()
```